# Facebook Error Codes list?

Tags: oauth, facebook-oauth

Is there a place where I can find complete list of Facebook's error codes?
In my app's stats I have a few 1340004 errors:

```
Method: dialog:oauth:touch
Error Code: 1340004
Failures: 436
Sampled Method Calls: 1,172
Failure Rate: 37.2%
```

But what the hell IS that 1340004 error?? The answer is nowhere to be found, and FB's docs got only a small list of payment erros, which are 138****.

Where's the doc for ALL FB error codes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I have the same error:

```
Method: dialog:oauth:popup
Error Code: 1340004
Failures: 410
Sampled Method Calls: 816
Failure Rate: 50,2%
```

This data is from 2 days ago, yesterday I reduced Failure Rate to 1'1% and I think that I will not have any failure today. I had a lot of errors with tokens, since 2 days ago I receive longer access_tokens, and I had in my DB a short varchar field for this access_token and the result was truncated access_tokens.

I changed this field yesterday, I suspect that I reduced this error for my fix, but I'm not sure.

Comment: My fix solved this error. I had an error with tokens that I was using because I was saving it truncated. Check this in your code, I hope I give you some clue for solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but no problems with token lengths on my side. I'm more concerned about error code descriptions - it's damn rude to tell people they have errors, and not explaining a bit what the heck is actually going on.