# Facebook API Errors (1340004) and (1348058)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, oauth

I'm trying to reduce the number of Facebook API Errors in our Unity Game and have currently got two error codes but cannot find anything on the FB developers website to help me locate and solve the problem. The error codes are display via Facebook Analytics.

---

> **Method:** dialog:oauth
>
> **Error Code:** 1340004
>
> **Error Message:** Not Logged In: You are not logged in. Please login and try again.
>
> **Failues:** 97.9K
>
> **Total Calls:** 227.4K
>
> **Failure Rate:** 43%

---

> **Method:** dialog:oauth
>
> **Error Code:** 1348058
>
> **Error Message:** Please Confirm Email: The email address you entered has already been registered, but your account hasn't been confirmed
>   yet. You'll get an email soon with details on how to confirm your
>   account.
>
> **Failues:** 32.4K
>
> **Total Calls:** 227.4K
>
> **Failure Rate:** 14.3%

---

I've not been able to recreate these myself so I'm not even sure if theses errors are client or server side but those failure rates seem really high.

Any calls I make via the client always checks the FB.IsLoggedIn is true before continuing and the documentation seems to indicate that the Facebook SDK handles refreshing Access tokens.

> Refreshing access tokens on Mobile
>
> The Facebook SDK will manage the lifetime of access tokens for you and
>   will handle making sure that tokens are refreshed before they expire.

The only other mention of the first error code (1340004) is from a stackoverflow post from 3 years ago ([link to post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15830166/facebook-error-codes-list))

The only mention of the second error code (1348058) is from a closed github issue ([link to post here](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook/issues/116)) which seems to suggest that the app age restriction was causing there issue but our apps age restriction is currently set to "Anyone (13+) on the Facebook settings.

The LIVE version is on (7.3.0) of the Facebook Unity SDK but I've updated to the latest on the version yet to be released.

---

The only thing we do server side is check the access token returns the user's Facebook id, see below.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id&access_token=%s
```

---

Basically, has anyone else experienced these error codes or has any ideas on how to reduce them?

Any help is much appreciated.